# Angular2 Custom Service not found

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am trying to use custom service for populating people list in my HTML. I've created custom service as per below:

**app.peopleListService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from "../model/peopleModel";


@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {
  constructor() { }

  getAll() : Person[] {
    return [
      {name: 'Luke Skywalker', height: 177, weight: 70},
      {name: 'Darth Vader', height: 200, weight: 100},
      {name: 'Han Solo', height: 185, weight: 85},
    ];
  }
}
```

I've register this provider in my module.ts

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent}  from './app.component';
import { PeopleService } from "../services/app.peopleListService";
@NgModule({
  imports:      [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
  providers: [ PeopleService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc -w"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.3.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10"
  }
}
```

**Systemjs.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
      myApp: 'app',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    packages: {
      myApp: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

But I am getting error in console like this:
[image]

Here is my project Structure in VS Code:
[image]

Comment: can you post your `package.json` code?

Comment: @hrdkisback - I added package.json  code

Comment: you should add your `systemjs.config.js`. The problem probably lies there. You've set the folder `app` to have the defaultExtension, but you did not do the same for the `services` folder

Comment: @PierreDuc - added systemjs.config.js as well

Comment: are you calling this from your app.component.ts? or from inside the folder peoplelist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either move your `services` folder into your `app` folder, which makes a lot more sense to do so, and change the import to

```
import { PeopleService } from "./services/app.peopleListService";
```

Or add a new package to your `systemjs.config.js`:

```
packages: {
  services: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
```

Comment: I've added package in systemjs.config.js as I don't want to change the structure of the folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `"./services/app.peopleListService"`

**module.ts**

```
import { PeopleService } from "./services/app.peopleListService";
```

Comment: I've tried same but VSCode shows me error not found